# jQuery Value Help

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having problems getting the value of the input field.

```
function Send(id){ 
var send_to=$("#id").val(); 
$.post("send.php", { id:id }, function(data) { if(data==="OK"){  } else { } }); 
}
```

Below is an example of the page.

```
<input type=text id=4543><button onclick=Send(4543);>SEND</button>
<input type=text id=8643><button onclick=Send(8643);>SEND</button>
<input type=text id=8645><button onclick=Send(8645);>SEND</button>
<input type=text id=2421><button onclick=Send(2421);>SEND</button>
```

I need to get the value of the input control whose id is passed to the send method.

Thank you! :)

Comment: $("#id").val(); this is always constant string /// which is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, then:

```
var send_to=$("#id").val();
```

should be

```
var send_to=$("#" + id).val();
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much! Stack Overflow saves the day again. :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all your id's are invalid(not in HTML5).

Also bind the handler in document ready function

```
<input type=text id="txt4543"><button class="btn">SEND</button>
<input type=text id="txt8643"><button class="btn">SEND</button>
<input type=text id="txt8645"><button class="btn">SEND</button>
<input type=text id="txt2421"><button class="btn">SEND</button>


$(function(){
    $(".btn").click(function(){
        var txtElem = $(this).prev();
        var value = txtElem.val();
        $.post("send.php", { id:txtElem.attr("id") }, function(data) { if(data==="OK"){  } else { } });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm sorry but I gave the answer to the other guy because he was first and it did solve my problem. BUT your way of doing it is better so I'm going to use your method. Thanks for taking the time to help me. :)

Comment: I'd give you both checks but can't. :(

Comment: The IDs are not valid in HTML 4 either: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name